# No data written: Not enough storage - Git on TFS 2015

Tags: git, tfs, commit, tfs-2015

Some git commits have vanished from our TFS server.

A developer had the following message :

[image: Failed to mmap. No data written: Not enough storage is available]

As TFS GIT stores commmits to an SQL DB we've checked disk & db space. Everything is ok.

The repo history was not rewritten.

We are looking for an explication. Anyone has an idea about what could happend and how to avoid this to happen again?

Comment: https://github.com/git-tfs/git-tfs/issues/621

Comment: how can I check the version of libgit2sharp?

Comment: This is a problem on the client, despite what that dialog says, it's a _Visual Studio_ issue.  What version of VS are you using?

Comment: Git doesn't store anything to the database. It stores objects in a local repository. You then *push* the objects to some other git repository. Does your local disk have enough space ? What VS version and update are you using?

Comment: @EdwardThomson VS 2015 Enterprise with update 3 (14.0.25425.01)

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos : have a look to : https://www.richard-banks.org/2014/02/tfs-internals-how-does-tfs-store-git.html . Its still the case in 2015.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry about that.  This is a bug in 32-bit versions of libgit2 on Windows, which is used by Visual Studio, and how it memory maps the pack files.  Although these issues have [largely](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3690) [been fixed](https://github.com/libgit2/libgit2/pull/3668) in newer versions of libgit2, this sadly will not help you push this repository with your current version of Visual Studio.

You'll need to push this change with the command line.

Comment: Do you know if it will be fixed in the next visual studio update?

Comment: @StevenMuhr Sorry, I do not, I no longer work on Visual Studio.

Comment: @StevenMuhr However, it should be fixed in VS "15" (confusingly, the next version of VS after 2015).